# Postgres procedure commands to assign to diffrent threads

Tags: postgresql

I have a stored procedures which contains few sql queries. Is it somehow possible to run each query as separated thread to speed it up? I use postgres 11.

Comment: Actually, pg needs to create a backend for every query ran in parallel, so I suppose that the option to implement "parallel" query execution would be to use the dblink extension. You can look at this function and execute queries in background: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-send-query.html

Comment: @Vicctor but this is to be used with dblink. I want to call sql queries against current database.

Comment: Dblink connects to the current database as well. However, the performance of such a solution will be bad.